# Prevent downloads from media folders in Magento

Tags: magento, watermark

Are there any new methods to prevent someone directly downloading a media file if they know the folder path to it on the server?
I know there never used to be, but wondered if anything new to this end had cropped up in the last couple of years?

Or maybe I missed something before and this was always possible??

My Magento 1.4.0.1 store has tons of images, a lot of which I have put a lot of woork into. I am using the Magento watermarking system, which works fine, but if you know the direct file system path to the image, you get served the original, non-watermarked image.

I'd like to stop that if possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this is to deny access to those folders via `.htaccess`. One of the bad habits that PHP leaves us with is putting everything inside of the web root, which as you say allows people to access individual files out of context of the website itself. However, you can place a file in any folder you like called `.htaccess` to block that access. The contents of the file should look something like this:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Note that this will still allow PHP to access the files to generate new thumbs, but will disallow all browser access to the files.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I tried adding this in the media/catalog/product folder (at the same level in Magento's structure as all the "first letter" folders of the media files). It now blocks access to images entirely (from the Catalog folder and all sub folders) including access by PHP - so no images are appearing on the website for any products?

Comment: Yes, that will deny all subfolders, too. You'll want to make sure that the image cache itself (where the watermarked images are stored) isn't affected.

Comment: Ah, got it! So Deny all in the main folder, and then Allow all in the cache (where the watermarked images are saved). This appears to work for me! Great, thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Would watermarking your images beforehand be an acceptable solution for you? You'll also save some cycles in the process. A simple [Google search](http://www.google.com?q=watermark+images) turned up some links to free (as in beer) watermarking tools. I haven't tested any of those, though.

Comment: It might be the best option open to me, unfortunately. There are literally thousands of images to contend with... I seriously hope there is another way!